# Taking register value and using it later as variable

Tags: ansible

I want to make the dynamic assigned ip to vm permanent by adding it to its ifcfg-eth0 file,, im having trouble at using the `register: eth0` value which is the actual ip address  and putting it in last line  `line: "IPADDR=register.stdout"`

```
---
 - hosts: all
   become: yes
   tasks:
   - name: getting ip address  of eth0
     shell: ip r l | grep  -e eth0 | grep default | grep  -oE "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"
     register: eth0

   - shell: rm -f /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
   - file: path="/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0" state=touch

   - blockinfile:
      dest: "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0"
      block: |
       DEVICE=eth0
       BOOTPROTO=static
       ONBOOT=yes
       USERCTL=no
       TYPE=Ethernet
       IPADDR=
       NETMASK=255.255.255.0
       GATEWAY=

   - name: adding ip in ifcfg-eth0
     lineinfile:
      dest: "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0"
      regexp: "IPADDR="
      line: "IPADDR=register.stdout"
```

error:

```
[tempuser@testing ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=register.stdout
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK[tempuser@testing ~]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the register variable eth0 by trying to use the name "register" which doesn't exist.

When you register a variable in ansible, you also tell ansible the name of the variable you want to register it as - in your case, eth0:

```
register: eth0
```

So to access it later, you would have to use the name eth0 like so:

```
IPADDR={{ eth0.stdout }}
```

---

Now, if you permit me to solve what I believe is an XY problem of yours - instead of using grep to parse out the ip address of your interface, why not try using ansible facts? If you know the interface name on the host, then you can simply do something like this:

```
IPADDR={{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
```

If, on the other hand, you do not know the interface name (or they are different on all your hosts) - but you do know that each host has only one viable interface, then you could use something like the following:

```
IPADDR={{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
```

To see all the facts that ansible collects on a system, use the following command:

```
ansible <hosts> -m setup
```

Comment: thank alot for pointing my silly mistake, but there is one more change regarding this its need to written like this to pull the value in file

`line: "IPADDR={{ eth0.stdout }}"`

Comment: You are right, of course - I apologize for the mistake. I edited that in now.

Comment: don't apologise buddy u saved me tons of times thanks